# Power management issues!

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm using an HP-15BS542TU laptop. I have been using it for the past 4 years with Windows 10. I recently installed Ubuntu about 2 months ago. While on windows, my laptop lasted 10 hours on a full battery, Ubuntu lasts hardly an hour. I'm am running an i3-6006u processor with 4 GB ram and integrated graphics. I read up on the power management guides by other users which direct you to use tlp. But I already tried that and there has been no improvement! I would like your help in fixing this problem. Please help me!!

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: sudharsan@sudharsan-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: @Raffa I tried tlp and it's been 3 days since I installed and enabled tlp on my machine. But there is no noticeable change. The machine still shuts down after an hour when not plugged in at 100%. is there any other alternate method?